# Time usage in "It's time we got back there"

Tags: past-tense

Why do we use the past in the sentence "It's time we got back there." ?

I would have used the present and I would have said "It's time we get back there".

Comment: If you are asked to choose between the two in an exam, you will have to choose the 'got back' one. This one refers to a hypothetical situation or the subjunctive mood. "I wish we got back there." If you know why 'got back' is used in this sentence, you can use the same logic to your exam question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one is acceptable.  Present tense is saying that the time has arrived to get back there, and past tense is implying that the time to get back there has come and gone.  A little more emphatic version would be "It's past time we got back there."

Comment: Ok, thank you. I asked this question because it was in an exam, and we had to choose between the two possibilities (without any context).

Comment: Tough exam question.  :)